# Ext.js TabPanel - sending chosen tab as a form parameter

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to send (as a html form parameter) which tab was chosen on submit? At the moment I have hidden form element and I set its value to tab value and that's how I recognize on server side which tab was active when data were submitted but it seems to me that there should be an easier way (some TabPanel parameter).

Here is my form hidden parameter `upit` which I dynamically set with JS:

```
function selectTab(tab){
    document.forms[0].upit.value = tab.value;
}

Tm.Report.createForm(
{
    items:
    [
        new Ext.form.TextField(
        {
            name: 'upit',
            value: '0',
            hidden: true
        }),
        
        new Ext.TabPanel(
        {
            activeTab: 0,
            items:
            [
        
                //TAB0
                {
                    listeners: {activate: selectTab},
                    value: 0,
                    items:
                    [
                       //...tab content
                    ]
                },
            
                //TAB1
                {
                    listeners: {activate: selectTab},
                    value: 1,
                    items:
                    [
                      //...tab content
                    ]
                }

            ]
        })
```

Comment: You can use [`getActiveItem()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/modern/Ext.tab.Panel.html#method-getActiveItem) method of the `Ext.tab.Panel`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `itemId` for your components, like:

```
new Ext.TabPanel(
    {
        activeTab: 0,
        itemId: 'reportForm',
        items:
        [
    
            //TAB0
            {
                listeners: {activate: selectTab},
                value: 0,
                itemId: 'TAB0',
                items:
                [
                   //...tab content
                ]
            },
        
            //TAB1
            {
                listeners: {activate: selectTab},
                value: 1,
                itemId: 'TAB1',
                items:
                [
                  //...tab content
                ]
            }

        ]
    });
```

Then you can get the tab name with:

```
 var tabPanel  =  Tm.report.down('#reportForm'),
     activeTab = tabPanel.getActiveTab(),
         tabId = activeTab.get('itemId');
```